# Is it possible in .NET to set the local endpoint (IP address) when using webclient to consume a web service

Tags: .net, ip

I'm wondering if it is possible using .NET to call a remote web service and in effect specify which IP the call is made on.

I'm consuming a service that limits the number of calls I can make based on IP.  The service costs in the 20k range after the free limit is used up.  I'm very close to enough calls but not quite there using the free service.  My server has 3 IP so I could in effect triple the number of calls I could make to the remote service by changing the IP.